# Clicking area of image to change that area's color

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one implement functionality similar to the one shown in this gif in a website?

[image: changing colour of part of image]

Specifically, the part where the user clicks on a (non-rectangular) area of the image and that area then changes colour.

A long, long time ago when the internet was still young, there was something called image maps. Is that still the preferred approach? I heard about svg, does that provide this type of functionality? What about canvas?

Comment: [Image maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) are still a valid option and HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about image maps to get them in this shape of hit areas. 
But I recommend using canvas for these type of applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for doing that, being image maps one of them. However, I wouldn't do it with it, nowadays, there are better solutions.

You can either use canvas, as suggested before, for example using a canvas library like http://fabricjs.com/ or, maybe a bit easier, using SVG elements.

The benefit of SVG is that they render as normal DOM elements in a website, so you can debug then in the inspector, attach normal click events to them, style them using CSS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

multiple options for this.

SVGs + CSS

CANVAS animations

FLASH( wouldn't recommend this option.,Pretty outdated)

Plain html css (But this wont be customisable in future for different shapes, a lot of time consuming when compared to other ways and confusing unless written with good documentation.)

html+css way: you can always make most of the geometrical shapes with css and html. But, curves we have svgs to go for and use css/svg transitions for visuals